# yii2 framework site on Windows 10 localhost - deployment issue

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've received an yii2 project zip archive and try to deploy the project on localhost(Windows10/Apache).
I've already install all the dependencies(composer install) and now try to open the site: using "yii serve" in cli and http://localhost:8080/ at my browser.

But something's wrong with it, I can see just html page which isn't working correctly, no js an css are being loaded. If I open the page source(Ctrl+U) I can see that there's no `<header></header>` tag with js and css at all. See the image attached:

[image]

Also, I've created a virtual host for the purpose but the result is the same.
I noticed that if I type http://localhost:8080/login?redirect=%2F it's loading all the js and css but saying: "Page not found".

Also, here is CMD console screenshot:

[image]

What can be the issue and how to get it working?
Thanks for advance!

Comment: to answer your question could your write localhost:8080/web/index.php
to see if your default controller is working correctly if not there is a lot of chances you are not acceding your default controller

Comment: show at least the console screenshot with the exception that is thrown, and the path that is loaded for the css and js files and also the correct path that should be used

Comment: It seems to me that assets are not being referenced with a relative URL, but a hard coded one. Check the network tab to see where te requests for the assets are going

Comment: to Amar Dje: http://localhost:8080/web/index.php - gives Page not found and just http://localhost:8080/web gives the same

Comment: To  Muhammad Omer Aslam: I've attached CMD console screenshot, images are being loaded.